# Remover estilo padrão do Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Quando eu crio uma lista ul com o atributo listview e coloca um link a href,
automaticamente o framework escurece o elemento da lista e coloca um ícone ao final. Como posso remover esse comportamento padrão ?

```
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>Jquery</li>
                <li><a href="#">teste</a><HTML</li>
                <li>CSS3</li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade `data-icon="false"`, ela elimina o icone.

Existem outras formas de fazer isso, mas eu considero esta a mais facil.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                <li>Jquery</li>
                <li><a href="#" >teste</a><HTML</li>
                <li>CSS3</li>
</ul>
```

[Exemplo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88r1yjf0/)